# Is NgForm in Angular a directive of components, structural or Attribute?

Tags: angular

Sorry if this is native question since I am a beginner. 
As said here https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives,

```
There are three kinds of directives in Angular:

Components—directives with a template.
Structural directives—change the DOM layout by adding and removing DOM elements.
Attribute directives—change the appearance or behavior of an element, component, or another directive
```

So, for NgForm, it is also a directive, does it belong to one of those three directives? If it is structural, it should be used with *, for Attribute, it should be in [], or it belongs to components?

Last, maybe I should ask in another post, what is the different meaning of NgForm vs ngForm?

Comment: According to the documentation: "NgFor - a structural directive that renders a template for each item in a collection." More at: 
 https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: I am asking NgForm,not NgFor ....I have searched the doc as far as I could but I don't think I could read all of the documents before I ask (as a Angular newbie as said) .

Comment: Sorry, my bad. As for the `NgForm` it's "component directive", you can find more at: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it  by process of elimination.
ngForm gives you a control for validation for example.
Of course with this control you can use other directives which change the DOM layout or the appearance or behavior of an element.

Comment: But you just answered your own question, giving three options of directives type. Logically 2 of them  does not fit. Look, that only leaves one option: component. So use reference like this #yourForm = "ngForm"

Comment: Thank you, understand now. As a new guy to Angular, sometime I have some guess and but want to get confirmation from expert :)